# Which image file format supports layers is compatible with both Photoshop and Photoimpact?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

I have a PSD file I'd like somebody to change some things. However, this guy only has PhotoImpact so he cannot open PSD files.

I'm looking for a format to save that file so he can open it in PhotoImpact while still having layer information (so JPG etc. are not a solution).

Comment: Does he have an older version of PhotoImpact?  As far as I can tell, versions 8 and later support Photoshop PSD files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PhotoImpact X3 can open PSDs and can save it. Furthermore, you can save your PSD as TIFF in Photoshop, where each layer is saved separately. This TIFF can be opened by PhotoImpact. In general there is no 100% way to edit PSD in PhotoImpact and save it back to PSD – both programs are not really compatible.